# How to prove $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leqslant 1$ if and only if for any $l>1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{l^n}=0$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $a_n>0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, how to prove $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leqslant 1$ if and only if for any $l>1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{l^n}=0$?

My proof.

Suppose $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leqslant 1$. Then $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{l^n}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{a_n}}{l}\right)^n\leqslant \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{l^n}=0~(l>1)$. Hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{l^n}=0$.

But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, since $a_n > 0$, $$\left \lvert \frac{a_n}{l^n} \right \rvert = \frac{a_n}{l^n}$$
so by your proof $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left \lvert \frac{a_n}{l^n} \right \rvert = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{l^n} \leq 0$$
hence $$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\left \lvert \frac{a_n}{l^n} \right \rvert \leq  \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left \lvert \frac{a_n}{l^n} \right \rvert = 0$$
and therefore $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{l^n} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{l^n} = 0.$$
You still have to proof the converse though.